# ERROR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rezg/logger/common/DebugLogProcessor

Tags: java, jboss, struts, noclassdeffounderror, struts-1

I started a project using Java and Struts. Please can anyone help me to understand this error. I am new to Java and Struts. Below you can see my error in console.

```
1842901 [http-0.0.0.0-8180-3] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/bbb].[action] - Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rezg/logger/common/DebugLogProcessor
    at bbb.r.xmlr.XMLAction.executeTask(XMLAction.java:146)
    at bbb.common.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:30)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:415)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at bbb.common.AuthFilterServlet.doFilter(AuthFilterServlet.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.CustomPrincipalValve.invoke(CustomPrincipalValve.java:39)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:159)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It means a class called DebugLogProcessor cannot be found and by the XML references in the error is probably because some misconfiguration of its declaration in a config file somewhere is likeley the problem.

Comment: @Samuel If some class is not found then it should be another exception named `ClassNotFoundException`.There's a difference between them, and the second is not in the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rezg/logger/common/DebugLogProcessor

means that the class definition is not found by the JVM runtime.

If you read a javadoc description of the exception

> [**NoClassDefFoundError**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html):
>
> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a `ClassLoader` instance tries to load in the *definition of a class* (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.
> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

To understand these things you should learn that a definition of a class is compiled by the Java compiler to the file with extension `.class`. There could be many such files after the compilation. When application is started it is looking for such files in the `classes` folder which is under `WEB-INF`. If you have many class files, then they  could be
assembled into the `.jar` file. Then this jar file is available on `classpath` in the `lib` folder.

**What means a message:**

`rezg/logger/common/DebugLogProcessor` it is a class named `DebugLogProcessor` in the package named `rezg.logger.common`.

**Conclusion:**

If some libraries or classes are missed from the application then you should rebuild it by adding missing dependencies before you deploy and run your application. Clean, refresh, rebuild are obvious tasks you do every time when you make some changes in the source code.

If you don't know where to get the missing class then you search them in the public repositories locally or remotely.

I also used a public resource for searching missing `.jar` files at [findjar.com](https://findjar.com)